# Best way to store 3 values?

Tags: c#

I need to store 3 values for my program.
The first value is a byte, the second is a another byte and last is a string.
And once I have used the values, I want to be able to remove them.

Should I store this by creating a object and give those 3 values as parameters? 
Or creating a 3-dimensional list?

Comment: Do you want to persist these values after your program terminates?  Or just keep them in memory?

Comment: @JonBates Just in memory

Answer (score 3):

Create a type that holds those three values.

```
class SomeData 
{
    private readonly byte _firstByte;
    private readonly byte _secondByte;
    private readonly string _stringData;

    public byte FirstByte { get { return _firstByte; }  }
    public byte SecondByte { get { return _secondByte; }  }
    public string StringData { get { return _stringData; } }

    public SomeData(byte first, byte second, string data) 
    {
        _firstByte = first;
        _secondByte = second;
        _stringData = data;
    }
}
```

The class as it is written is immutable, but you can progressively open it up to modification depending on your needs.

Regarding removing the values once you've use them: any instances of `SomeData` you no longer have a reference to are automatically cleaned up by the GC.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution might be to use a `Tuple`, if this is suitable for your needs, e.g.

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create(someBytes, moreBytes, myString);
```

You can access the values using `tuple.Item1`, `tuple.Item2`, and `tuple.Item3`.

---

You can of course also use multiple `Tuple`s if you require this, e.g.

```
var list = new List<Tuple<byte, byte, string>> {
    tuple,
    anotherTuple,
    thirdTuple,
    etc
};
```

---

As others have mentioned though, if you're referencing "like" data, you should create a `class` instead.

Comment: What do you mean with "like" data?

I am needing this for my Connect4 game.
It checks where there is 2 in a row, and then it it will add the data.
The first value being if it's player 1 OR 2.

Comment: As @JonBates has described in his answer, basically. For example storing information about a car, such as `make`, `model`, `colour`, etc.

Comment: You can omit type parameters with [`Tuple.Create()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @unarist Nice, I didn't know about that method - that makes things [slightly easier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455581/tuple-create-vs-new-tuple) - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If they are related, put them in a class and have the values as fields or properties.

Once they object is no longer used, it will be garbage collected, so it will be automatically removed.

Comment: How does the program know when it's no longer being used? I can't do .Remove like I would with an array/list ?

Comment: When nothing in the program uses the object anymore, it automatically gets removed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want a halfway point between a `Tuple` and a `class`, try a `struct`.

```
    struct MyStruct
    {
        private byte _byte1;
        private byte _byte2;
        private string _string1;

        public byte Byte1 { get { return _byte1; } }
        public byte Byte2 { get { return _byte2; } }
        public string String1 { get { return _string1; } }

        public MyStruct(byte byte1, byte byte2, string string1)
        {
            _byte1 = byte1;
            _byte2 = byte2;
            _string1 = string1;
        }

    }
```

Usage:

```
    MyStruct thisthing = new MyStruct((byte)1, (byte)0, "Howdy!");

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", thisthing.Byte1, thisthing.Byte2, thisthing.String1));
```

Output:

```
1,0,Howdy!
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how related your items are.  If they relate to the same parent (e.g. you are modelling a Car, and you are storing TransmissionType, Proce and Make), it would make sense to store the variables in a class.

If they are only 'working values', e.g. ones required to calculate some proble, I would store them as three variables.

My reasoning is that in months time, a well-names variable (possibly in a well-named class) will make it obvious what they are used for, without having to trawl the codebase for clues.